# How are the natural sunlight effects achieved while shooting?

Tags: film-techniques, lighting

While watching *Seinfeld*, many times I have noticed the natural (seems like natural?) sunlight coming through windows of Jerry's apartment.

[image]

Same light effect can be seen at the cafe.

[image]

How are such natural light effects achieved in TV shows (or even movies)?

Two possibilities/sub-questions:

1. If artificial lights are used to achieve these effects, how *exactly* it is done so? What kind of lights and setups are used? Because to me, it looks too natural to be achieved through the artificial lights.
2. Is it possible that it is actually a natural sunlight? If yes, how is that possible with an indoor studio setup in which typically majority of the sitcoms are shot? Or is it not uncommon to have outdoor studio setups for sitcoms?

Comment: http://www.cybercollege.com/tvp030.htm

Answer (score 3):

Two simple ways.

1. Shot on Location or an outdoor set in real light.
2. Any number of lighting sources that have daylight white temperature and CRI (color quality). It's not difficult to have artificial light that mimics daylight through a false window.

Seinfeld specifically was shot on sound stages and purpose built sets. What you see is combinations of natural and artificial light.